# Borrar usuario GAM

Tags: genexus

Uso GeneXus 15, .net e IIS. Borro un usuario `GAM` desde el *backend* y cuando quiero registrarme con el mismo usuario me dice:

> Ya existe el registro GAM(42)

Vi que permanece en la Tabla de usuarios de `GAM`. Es un borrado lógico. La pregunta es:

¿Puedo borrarlo definitivo para luego volver a registrarme con el mismo usuario?

Les paso el código del evento:

```
Event Enter
    if Captcha1.ValidationResult=1
        If &GAMPassword = &GAMPasswordConf
            if &UsrId<>""
                //modo edicion
                &User.GUID          = &UsrId
            endif
            &User.Name          = &UsrId
            &User.EMail         = &UsrEmail
            &User.Birthday      = &UsrFechaNac
            &User.Password      = &GAMPassword

            &User.Save()

            If &User.Success() 
                &Usr.UsrId=&UsrId
                &Usr.UsrActivo=true //lo activo dentro de la webapp pero en GAM requiere activación via el link incrustado en el mail
                &Usr.UsrEmail=&UsrEmail
                &Usr.UsrFechaNac=&UsrFechaNac
                &Usr.UsrPaisCdg=&UsrPaisCdg
                &Usr.UsrUltFchHr=servernow()
                &Usr.Save() 
                if &Usr.Success()
                    Commit
                    &Repository = GAMRepository.Get()
                    If &Repository.UserActivationMethod = GAMUserActivationMethod.User
                        &ActivactionKey = &User.GetActivationKey(&Errors)
                        &CuerpoMail = GetBodyActivarUsuario.Udp(&ActivactionKey)
                        EnviarMail.Call(&UsrEmail,"Activación de usuario",&CuerpoMail)
                        Msg("Se envió un mail a "+&UsrEmail.Trim()+" para activar el usuario. Si no lo recibe en su bandeja, por favor revisar su carpeta SPAM.")
                    endif
                else
                    for &Message in &Usr.GetMessages()
                        NuevoLog.Call(&Pgmname + "#" + &Message.Description)
                    endfor
                endif
            else        
                &Errors = &User.GetErrors()
                Do 'DisplayMessages'
            endif
        Else
            Msg("La clave y su reingreso no coinciden.")
        Endif
    else
        Msg("Debe validar el captcha")
    endif
EndEvent
```

Comment: Probé borrar un usuario desde el backend de `GAM` y luego agregar el mismo y funciona. Parecería ser algo al hacerlo por el código, edité la pregunta e incruste el código para que puedan ver.

Answer (score 1):

Te debería dejar crear otro usuario con el mismo identificador de usuario. Te recomiendo que lo veas a través de [soporte GeneXus](https://www.genexus.com/developers/Foros?es) pues parece tratarse de un error.